# why is my Nth Prime Number in Ruby not efficient?

Tags: ruby, iteration, primes

I'm doing the following challenge on Coderbyte and it doesn't compute some of the bigger numbers, so I'm assuming that my function is slow. On my computer, it takes 0.045 seconds to compute the 1000th prime number.

The prompt is:

Have the function PrimeMover(num) return the numth prime number. The range will be from 1 to 10^4. For example: if num is 16 the output should be 53 as 53 is the 16th prime number.

Use the Parameter Testing feature in the box below to test your code with different arguments.

Here's my code:

```
def PrimeMover(num)
  start = Time.now
  return 2 if num == 1
  return 3 if num == 2
  return 5 if num == 3  
  counter = 3
  7.upto(10**4).each do |n|
    next if n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0
    (2..((n**0.5).to_i)).each do |m|
      break if n % m == 0
      counter += 1 if m == (n**0.5).to_i
    end
    p Time.now - start if counter == num
    return n if counter == num
  end
end
```

Comment: well taking that square root each time probably won't help.

Comment: it takes 2 full seconds to find the 1000th prime number when I change (n**0.5).to_i to just n. I'm not sure what I'm doing that is slowing down the process.

Comment: that's clearly not what I meant...cache the value

Comment: ahh that actually helped I think (if I interpreted correctly)!! I gave (n**0.5).to_i a variable and replaced the 2 instances of that with the variable. The new result I'm getting when I find the 1000th prime number is 0.013 seconds, which is about 3x faster.

Comment: what is your code's [empirical orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)? is the only way to assess its "speed". One datapoint says nothing. :)

Comment: I would suggest caching primes too, you are only interested in `n % m` where `m` is a prime.

Comment: Take into account that Coderbyte & your system/machine is not the same, the connection between your computer and Coderbyte server may be bad, there might be lots of users that evaluate codes on their servers.. etc. On my pc(it's old) with 1,6GHz Sempron, 1GB ram it takes ~0.173_125(I used `100.times` and divided by 100).

Comment: This question is almost certainly a duplicate. You can learn from pretty much any question asking how to speed up a prime number function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby, but it looks like you're using trial division to find primes, ie., for each number (counter), you're checking if it's divisible by any number up to that number's square root.

Use the [Sieve of Erastothenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Erastothenes) instead. Basically, as you find primes, look ahead and mark all the multiples of each of those primes as composite. The next number that isn't marked composite is prime.

If you choose to mark off multiples up to a limit n, you only need to mark the multiples of primes up to sqrt(n).

I've solved [this same problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7) before in python at project euler, where the problem statement called for the 10,001st prime. Like you, I started with trial division and found my program to be unbearably slow.